# Probability with a 7-sided dice

Tags: probability, dice

I have this : "We roll a 7-sided dice n times. What is the lower value of n to have 60% of chance to have 2 same value"

And I don't know how I can resolve this ... I know that the result is 5 but I've try to use Binomial distribution but I don't find the right result.

Comment: The binomial distribution is not really relevant. If toss twice, probability they are **different** is $6/7$, If toss three times the probability they are all different is $(6/7)(5/7)$. Continue until the product is $\le 0.4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need the binomial theorem for this. Consider the chance of *not* having any two matching values. Each roll must then be one of the values not obtained by any of the previous rolls. In $n$ rolls this will be
$$
Q(n) =\frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot \frac{5}{7} \cdots \frac{8-n}{7}
$$
So you have to find the lowest $n$ such that $Q(n) < 0.4$.
$$Q(1) = 1 \\
Q(2) = \frac{6}{7} \approx 0.85 \\
Q(3) = \frac{30}{49} \approx 0.61 \\
Q(4) = \frac{120}{343} \approx 0.35 < 0.4
$$
So the answer is that **4** rolls suffices to get the probability of a match above 60%.

Comment: Oh I have understand now thank you very much ! :).

And if you want to have 60% of chance to obtain at least one other value like the first value obtain? how can I make this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try instead to count the number of possible rolls that have all values distinct.  Note that there are 7 possible values for the first roll, 6 possible values for the second, et cetera.  To compute the probability, divide by $7^n$ for the set of all possible rolls.  Finally subtract the probability that all rolls are distinct from 1 to get the probability that at least one value is repeated.

Comment: so ? how can I should try to find the value ? What is the approach ?